# TFBuild access local file system

Tags: cordova, tfs, build, azure-devops

I'm trying to setup a continuous integration build service with TFS/TFBuild.

I am trying to build an Cordova app for iOS and Android, therefore i need to sign the apk/ipa.

I need a p12 certificate file for iOS and a keystorefile for android.

I do not want to check in therese files in the VCS, is there any ways to store them local in the system of the build agent and give cordova the local paths?

If I am trying to set a path it is always using a relative path to the cloned repository, even if I am using predeifned variables like $(AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY).

Any way of accessing the local filesystem where the agent runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova task uses relative path for keystore/p12 file just as you found:
[image]

But you can place the keystore/p12 file in the build agent and then add a "Copy Files" task before Cordova build task to copy the certificate file to the cloned repository folder before the cordova build task start and then you can set the relative path in Cordova build task.

Following task copys "test.log" file from "E:\a1" folder to "hello" folder in repository folder:
[image]

Comment: I tried exactly that, but copy files uses a relative path from the repo too :/  Edit: Oh Wait, seems like i can use variables there, i will try!

Comment: @StefanS Copy Files task does not require relative path, you can enter the absolute path to the file or use a predefined variable.

Comment: it seems like $(Agent.BuildDirectory) is the only variable that i can use. Any other folder says: Not found SourceFolder: /Users/***/myagent/_work/build/***/repo/$(agent.homedirectory)

Comment: @StefanS How do you configure the copy file task?

Comment: Not found SourceFolder: /Users/*/myagent/_work/build/*/repo/~/test  http://prntscr.com/bv3yot

Comment: @StefanS See my updated answer for the settings of "Copy Files" task.

Comment: @StefanS Your setting is trying to copy the keystore file from the "test" folder under repository folder to $(Agent.BuildDirectory) folder.

Comment: yea as i a m using a mac i thought i could use ~ to get to my home directory. with an absolute path from / it does "work", but crashes with an unhandled error: Unhandled: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/*/myagent/_work/_logs/pages/baaae9b0-4e42-11e6-a74e-d975afacb96c_1.page'  <- as the error says, this logfile does not exist

Comment: The error is, that it can#t find the logfile it wants to write to.. therefore there is no log file, the build log says nothing else than this error. but i got it working, i think it was regarding my pattern, made a new fodler with a the files and copied ** and it worked.  thank you.

Comment: Well it isn't solved completely. I can copy a file now, but not into my repository. if i am using $build.sourcesdirectory as the destination, it does create a folder in myagent/_work/build/*/$(build.sourcesdirectory) and does not use the variable. the same happens for every variable like $(Build.Repository.LocalPath) too. But the description says that i can use variables..

Comment: Log says: 2016-07-20T07:51:37.943Z: Copying /Users/*/certs/android/release/*.keystore to $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/*.keystore. Am i using variable in any wrong way? http://prntscr.com/bv4yzk

Comment: @StefanS Do you mean it will create a folder named "$(build.sourcesdirectory)" instead of copy the files to the path of "$(build.sourcesdirectory)"?

Comment: exactly, tried with several different variables, always new folder in _work/*/ instead of using the file path. tied with lowercase, PascalCase, did not change anything

Comment: Any idea, or should i create a new question for that problem?

Comment: @StefanS Yes, create a new question and provide detailed steps, screenshots and logs in it. :)